# Updating forms from service when going back and forth between pages Angular2

Tags: forms, angular, data-binding, service

I have an angular 2 (stable release) app (multiple pages with forms) where as the user fills out the form and goes to the next page with a submit I update a service object (form values firstname: value, lastname: value etc) and the user is navigated to the next page (form).

Once the user is taken to next page, the service object is updated with the values collected on the previous page.  However, if the user hits the back button or click the link to go back to the previous page the form is empty. I want to be able to fill the values which were collected in the service object.  I have tried reading about the 4 different ways of binding in angular2 and it does not seem to work. I tried using *ngIf to see if I can check for the service object property and repopulate the form if the user navigates back to the previous page via the back button or a provided link. Please note I am getting no errors.  Just not understanding  how binding work. Any help on how to solve this is appreciated.

Here is my Component and the associated Html template (snippets)
**start-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../services/user-service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-start',
  templateUrl: './start.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./start.component.css']
})
export class StartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private _userSerivce: UserService,
    private _router: Router,
   ) {
    console.log(_userSerivce);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  startSubmitted: boolean = this._userSerivce.startComplete;

  onSubmit(value: any){
    //console.log(value);
    this._userSerivce.startComplete = true;
    this._userSerivce.start = value;
    console.log(this._userSerivce.startComplete);
    console.log(this._userSerivce.start);
    this._router.navigate(['personal']);
  }

}
```

Snippet from **Start.component** template

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <app-side-nav-bar></app-side-nav-bar>

  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <h1>Start</h1>
    <form autocomplete='off' novalidate #form="ngForm"(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">

    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input
          class="form-control" type="text"
          required
          name="firstName"
          ([ngModel])='firstName'
          [value]='firstName'
         >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lg-pad"></div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So as the user advances from page to page a service is updated with the values the user types.  If they hit the back button the ngInit lookup the values in the service and updated the form.  This was really simple to do.  In addition I also implemented local storage to store the form values.